# Can an electrician with 16th edition rules do work in anybody's home?

Tags: electrical, wiring, uk

I did an elim course taking city and guilds for the 16th edition electrical installation and maintenance. Can I still do work in people's houses without having to give certificates the types of work?

I want to add or move sockets, lighting and install new consumer units. Can I do this without having to get a permit as well?

Comment: You'd want to tell us where you are. What's an "elim course"?

Comment: @isherwood 16th edition is the UK... 17th is actually the current version - 16th was blue, 17th is red/pinkish... They are actually the Wiring Regulations and a British Standard - first published back in 1887 or 1888 iirc

Answer (score 4):

1. You can do work in people's houses, but you **must** certify your work to the **current** (Eighteenth) Edition of the Wiring Regulations. This is a legal requirement under part P of the Building Regulations in England. (Wales and Scotland have similar provisions.) The Wiring Regulations require either a Minor Works Certificate, or a Design Installation and Test Certificate for **all** wiring work.
2. If you carry out **notifiable** work such as installing new circuits, working in a kitchen, or installing a new consumer unit, *in a dwelling* then you **must** *either* notify the work to Building Control *or* be a member of a self-certification scheme such as NICEIC, NAPIT etc.

If you notify the work to Building Control they may require the certificates to be completed by a person with a **current** qualification. If you wish to apply to be a member of a self-certification scheme they will require you to have current qualifications or to be supervised by a qualified supervisor.

Small jobs which are non-notificable must still be certificated by you to the current Regulations and the certificate supplied to the customer. Forms of certificates are prescribed by the regulations and samples are available from IET.

The above applies to dwellings (including outbuildings and gardens). If you are working in **non-domestic buildings** then the notification requirement does not apply, but the **Electricity at Work Regulations** do (they would apply to you as a worker, and to your client as a business) and they would require a person to be **competent**. Evidence of competence is your qualification. For some work a 16th Edition qualification *may* remain satisfactory evidence of competence, for others it will not. For example, the Eighteenth Edition requires consideration of surge protection in designing an installation, and requirements for RCDs to all sockets and all concealed wiring even in permitted zones has changed since 16th Edition expired in 2004.

Comment: Have to vote this up as it is the only answer which is referring to the relevant regulations...

Answer (score 1):

This is going to depend on municipality in the US.   But the short answer is no.   Unless you are a certified electrician you usually cannot work on other people's stuff.

I have passed quite a few local electrical exams to work on my own houses but it is clear in every city I have taken one that this does not give me the right to do work for other people.   And in almost all cases there were limits to the work I was doing - most had a 3 circuit install max.

So you need to ask...

Now changing outlets and doing lighting, you can do these as a handiman but not as an electrician where you would be able to get a permit signed-off.

Comment: This is not the US and "municipality" is not relevant - the regulations in the UK are country-wide and the **only** body that can make changes are the Institute of electrical Engineers - which is why there are 17 editions (each of which have had updates over time).

Comment: Well, the OP failed to state where they were, so let's not jump on people for trying to help...

Comment: Got to upvote the op did not say where they where and @dmore did state that “in the U.S. , others agree should to help reverse the - as I have, 16 regulations sounds like some one that doesn’t know anything at all about electrical work but IS referring to the 17 code,,  OOPS The 2017 national electric code the most adopted code on this planet! Or something similar that was adopted in 16.

Comment: @J.Raefield I made the comment to Isherwood before the answer was visible - may have been a server timing issue though.

Comment: @solar Mike the NEC is the most adopted electrical code on the planet. Sorry to hurt your feelings but fire departments do not change It & it is not just the USA that uses it (not all US states do) but other countries also use it. How many homes are under your code? In the us alone over 100,000,000 homes and add business and we add another 60,000,000 buildings and that’s just on the mainland, an apprentice told me that a couple years back when we’re reviewing his class work. This doesn’t include the territory’s and other countries that use it. Look at all the questions and where they are from.

Comment: @EdBeal biggest is not always best... so many examples...

Comment: @Ed Isn't the National Electric Code developed by the National Fire Protection Association? And the local governments base their codes on that? At least that is what is said on p200 from "Hospitality Facilities Management & Design 3rd ed... Only reference I have to hand...

Comment: I had to upvote. We're here to try and help.

Comment: @solar mike again you are wrong only 4 states in the IS have not adopted the NEC. So it is a national code as the name states.  Mexico, Columbia, Venezuela, and Costa Rica are other countries that have adopted the code.

Comment: Well I am glad a miss spell made your day we also have main breaker isolation required, our code is used by 5 countries  with major sections used in many others. The NEC code has been around since 1897 it is developed by ANSI / NFPA and is updated every 3 years.

Comment: @SolarMike " in the UK the distribution board has an ELCB that protects the whole installation" whole-house RCDs have been deprecated since 16th Edition and not permitted since 17th Edition